# Count only null values in two different columns and show in one select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, count

I want to count just the null values in a specific column and all the null values in another
specific column, however i want my result to have both of these results shown in one table.

Here is what i have so far:

```
Select Count(*) as 'Column1Count', Count(*) as 'Column2Count'
   from table1
       Where column1 is null
     and column2 is null
```

please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work :

```
select
    (select count(*) from table1 where column1 is null) as 'Column1Count',
    (select count(*) from table1 where column2 is null) as 'Column2Count';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a case for that:

```
select  sum(case when Column1 is null then 1 end) as Col1Count
,       sum(case when Column2 is null then 1 end) as Col2Count
from    table1
```

Comment: thank you, the case in this query i have never used but this gave me the correct output